# Checking that a method parameter is a class constant

Tags: php

At the moment i am trying to create a helper class for our template designers, that have minimal PHP knowledge, so i would like to make it as fool proof as possible.

In that process i have stumbled upon a question i never really considered before:

**How does one check to see if a parameter to a method call is the value of a defined class constant?**

I can think of several ways to do it using reflection or the like, but was wondering if there is some way more simple that i have overlooked.

Taking a class like the following:

```
class Foo{
  const TYPE_A = 'A';
  const TYPE_B = 'B';
  const TYPE_C = 'C';

  public static function doSomething($type){
    //Check to see if $type is indeed a class constant
  }
}

//This would work
Foo::doSomething(Foo::TYPE_A);
Foo::doSomething(Foo::TYPE_B);
Foo::doSomething(Foo::TYPE_C);
Foo::doSomething('A');
Foo::doSomething('B');
Foo::doSomething('C');

//This should fail
Foo::doSomething('BAR');
```

Besides using reflection i could just use a private array or the like, but that would really defeat the purpose of the constants, or require that data is updated several places.

Comment: [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstants.php) **is** the way to go. use that with `in_array`. alternatively, you could *wrap* your values in classes themselves and use typing: `public static function doSomething(FooConstant $type) {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not seem to be possible without reflection or custom hacks so i am closing this

Answer (score -1):

You can check if the constant is defined with http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php

```
  public static function doSomething($type){
    if (defined('self::' . $type)) {
      // do someting
    }
  }
```

Comment: That would only work if the value of the constant is the same as the name of the constant, but i guess it could be done like that.